# Django REST + Angular Router

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

**Задача**: реализовать роутинг на стороне ангуляра, на стороне Django REST - только работа с собственным api.

Возник вопрос, как скоординировать работу urls.py у Django и routerProvider у Angular, и куда положить шаблоны? Как указать путь к шаблонам templateUrl?
Сейчас шаблоны лежат в соответствующей папке шаблонов приложения `myapp/templates/`

В основном hmtl подключаю angular-route.js и js:

```
var app = angular('myApp', ['ngRouter']);
app.config(function($routerProvider) {
   $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
             controller: 'someController1',
             templateUrl: 'template1.html'
        }
        .when('/page1/:id', {
             controller: 'someController2',
             templateUrl: 'template2.html'
        }

});
```

Также подключаю js с контроллерами someController1 и someController2.

В Django REST urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'myapi/'), include('myapp.urls')),
] + static.static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Обновление:**
В settings.py в TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS добавил две записи: `'django.core.context_processors.media' и 'django.core.context_processors.static'.`

В urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^myapi/', include("myapi.urls")),
   ] + static.static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static.static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

Переместил шаблоны в /static/myapp/templates/
В шаблонах, вернее, в base.html, который подключаю во всех шаблонах, добавил в head:
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRouter']);   
    app.constant('DJANGO_SETTINGS', {
            staticUrl: '{{ STATIC_URL }}',
            mediaUrl: '{{ MEDIA_URL }}'
        });
    app.config(stateConfig);
    stateConfig.$inject = ['$routerProvider', 'DJANGO_SETTINGS'];

function stateConfig($stateProvider, DJANGO_SETTINGS) {
       $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
             controller: 'someController1',
             templateUrl: DJANGO_SETTINGS.staticUrl + 'myapp/templates/template1.html'
        }
        .when('/page1/:id', {
             controller: 'someController2',
             templateUrl: DJANGO_SETTINGS.staticUrl + 'myapp/templates/template2.html'
        }
};
```

Выдает ошибку `AttributeError at / 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'`

**Обновление 2:**

Переделал на:

```
angular('myApp', ['ngRouter']);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .config(stateConfig);

stateConfig.$inject = ['$routerProvider', 'DJANGO_SETTINGS'];

function stateConfig($stateProvider, DJANGO_SETTINGS) {
       $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
             controller: 'someController1',
             templateUrl: DJANGO_SETTINGS.staticUrl + 'myapp/templates/template1.html'
        }
        .when('/page1/:id', {
             controller: 'someController2',
             templateUrl: DJANGO_SETTINGS.staticUrl + 'myapp/templates/template2.html'
        }
};
```

Та же ошибка.

**Обновление 3:**

Добавил импорт: from django.conf.urls import patterns
и переделал `urlpatterns = [...] + ...` на `urlpatterns = patterns(...) + ...`. В urls.py для приложения аналогично. Ошибки теперь этой нет.
Пока остается вопрос, как и куда прописывать редирект для корня сайта? В роутинге ангуляра я его прописал, а в `django urls` оставил только для своего `api`, но если открываю корень сайта, то возникает ошибка, что такой страницы нет, т.к. в urls.py корень `/` не прописан. Иными словами - как скоординировать url.py в django и роутинг в ангуляре?

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант:

Можно передавать путь до STATIC и MEDIA и шаблона django в приложение angular.js.
В настройках django надо добавить в TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS две записи:
'django.core.context_processors.media' и 'django.core.context_processors.static'

На время разработки [добавить в urlpatterns обработку url-ов для статики](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development):

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

В head шаблона django добавить константу для angular приложения:

```
<script>
    angular.module('myApp')
        .constant('DJANGO_SETTINGS', {
            staticUrl: '{{ STATIC_URL }}',
            mediaUrl: '{{ MEDIA_URL }}'
        });
</script>
```

В приложении angular работать как с обычной константой, инджектить, куда хочется, добавлять как префикс к шаблонам и так далее. Сами шаблоны положить в директорию static джанговского приложения, например, в static/myapp/templates/

```
angular('myApp', ['ngRouter']);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .config(stateConfig);

stateConfig.$inject = ['$routerProvider', 'DJANGO_SETTINGS'];

function stateConfig($stateProvider, DJANGO_SETTINGS) {
       $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
             controller: 'someController1',
             templateUrl: DJANGO_SETTINGS.staticUrl + 'myapp/templates/template1.html'
        }
        .when('/page1/:id', {
             controller: 'someController2',
             templateUrl: DJANGO_SETTINGS.staticUrl + 'myapp/templates/template2.html'
        }
};
```

Второй вариант:

Разрабатывать angular приложение с использованием [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache). Обычно все шаблоны собирают в один большой файл, в котором они по очереди добавляются в templateCache, templateUrl является ключом.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('template1.html', '<тут содержимое шаблона>');
});
```

Ну, и третий вариант: генерировать js средствами django, тогда и с путями проблем не будет и можно роутер динамически весьма легко создавать. Но очень неоднозначное решение получается.

Comment: На время разработки добавить в urlpatterns обработку url-ов для статики:

`urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`  - а если у меня уже есть `+ static.static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`?

Comment: если делаю по Вашему первому варианту и добавляю оба (STATIC + MEDIA), то ругается: `AttributeError at /

'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'`. И еще вопрос по поводу добавления в urlpatterns обработку url-ов для статики на время разработки - а в итоговом варианте как лучше сделать?

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил пример кода

Comment: про resolve ошибку исправил. Но остался вопрос, как и куда прописывать редирект для корня сайта? В роутинге ангуляра я его прописал, а в `django urls` оставил только для своего `api`, но если открываю корень сайта, то возникает ошибка, что такой страницы нет, т.к. в urls.py корень `/` не прописан

Comment: А что должно происходить при обращении к корню сайта?

Comment: должно срабатывать вот это правило для корня в ангуляр роутере: `$routeProvider
        .when('/', {
             controller: 'someController1',
             templateUrl: DJANGO_SETTINGS.staticUrl + 'myapp/templates/template1.html'
        }` т.е. открываться шаблон `myapp/templates/template1.html` и для него отрабатывать контроллер `someController1` для заполнения данных в шаблоне.

Comment: Тогда вам надо создать View, чтобы отдать страницу, которая загрузит angular приложение. Это может быть простая статичная страница, к которой подключены нужные js скрипты. TemplateView подойдет для такого.

Comment: в url.py прописать тогда его только для корня?для  /page1/:id  не нужно? `$routeProvider
        .when('/', {... }
        .when('/page1/:id', {...}`

Comment: Django у вас отвечает за доставку одностраничного приложения и за api. А у angular-а urls по-умолчанию используют url fragment (то, что находится в самом конце url и начинается с #).

Comment: т.е. в ангуляре вместо /page1/:id нужно использовать адрес вида #page1/:id ? даже, наверное, #page1_:id?

Comment: Зависит от реализации. Лучше у специалистов по angular спрашивать.